# migration of code from SP2007 to SP2010

Tags: migration

I have a small project based on SP2007, I have to re-built it on SP2010 as a sandbox solution. How we can start and do it. Can anyone provide me and link documents where each steps are mentioned in details.

Comment: If you do not have fancy dll references in your project you  can install a SP2007 solution on a SP2010 server.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a SP2010 Sandbox solution in Visual Studio will be almost the same (and even easier) as with your previous SP2007 (farm) solution. Tip: use Visual Studio 2012 it contains a lot of new functionality and makes SharePoint development a lot less frustrating.

Keep in mind that there are some (security) restrictions when developing a sandbox solution. It might be possible that you can not port all functionality to a sandbox solution.

Starting from SP2013, using .NET code in sandbox solution is not officially supported anymore (although it still seems to work). So for simplicity sake I would not convert your current SP2007 (farm) solution to a sandbox solution but I would simply update it to a SP2010 (farm) solution. You can do the same process later when migrating to SP2013 (on-premise).

Answer (score 0):

These links could be beneficial:

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/de6e05e3-bef1-4294-949a-30478fb29a9e/migrate-a-solution-sharepoint-2007-2010?forum=sharepointadminprevious
- [Migrating a solution from 2007 to 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10842/migrating-a-solution-from-2007-to-2010)
- http://geekswithblogs.net/juanlarios/archive/2011/03/29/upgrading-sharepoint-2007-projects-to-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Please let me know if you face any issue.